# Best way to lowercase and join the contents of an array except an given constant

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

What is the best way to lowercase and join the contents of the array into a string except that the constant does not have to be lowercase.

```
var PEOPLE = 'PEOPLE';
var arr = ['people', 'PEOPLE', 'People', 'pEOPLE', 'PeoPlE'];
var result = '';
$.each(arr, function (index, value) {
    if (value !== PEOPLE) {
        value = value.toLowerCase();
    }
    result = result + ' ' + value;
});
console.log(result); // result = 'people PEOPLE people people people';
```

Comment: What is the end result you're trying to obtain? I'm not sure I understand the question

Comment: I do not understand either, I ran this javascript and it worked like your title suggests it should work like.

Comment: @Antony I have updated the question.

Comment: @MukeshIngham How do i make this code better.

Comment: Your code gives this output... did you even test it?

Comment: @MukeshIngham I asked for help so that the answer given by me can be improved. I am a new programmer. I want to learn how the pros out there find a native solution like mine to improve.

Comment: @shawnderik the best advice I can give to a new programmer is don't make things too complicated. If your code works, it works. Infact it is very easy to understand and well laid out which is good. Less lines is not always better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution using `Array.prototype.map()` and `Array.prototype.join()` functions:

```js
var PEOPLE = 'PEOPLE', 
    arr = ['people', 'PEOPLE', 'People', 'pEOPLE', 'PeoPlE'],
    result = arr.map(function(w) {
      return w !== PEOPLE? w.toLowerCase() : w;
    }).join(' ');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the awesome reply.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var result = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + ' ' + (b !== 'PEOPLE' ? b.toLowerCase() : b);
});
```

Output:

```
"people PEOPLE people people people"
```

This also works:

```
var result = arr.map(function(a) {
  return a !== 'PEOPLE' ? a.toLowerCase() : a;
}).join(' ');
```

Comment: Thank you for the awesome reply. Loved the map and the join implementations.